# автоматическое определение параметров в шаблоне класса

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

пытаюсь спроектировать шаблонный класс который хранит унарную функцию(указатель на неё) с его типом аргумента и типом выходного параметра. Затем пытаюсь создать объект данного класса с использованием определённой унарной функции(см. исходник). Всё то вроде бы и удалось, но аппетиты выросли. хотелось бы доработать (возможно класс или что-то ещё) чтобы он уже не требовал параметры шаблона. Ведь скажем функция `std::ptr_fun` умеет.

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename arg0, typename res0>
struct F1 {
    typedef arg0 arg;
    typedef res0 res;
    typedef arg(*func)(res x);
    func f;
    F1(func _f) : f(_f) {}
    res0 operator()(arg0 x) { return f(x); }

};
char foo(int u) { return 's'; }





template<typename arg0, typename res0>
F1<arg0, res0> F1_func(typename F1<arg0, res0>::func _func) {
    return F1<arg0, res0>(_func);
}


int main() { 

    auto F1 = F1_func<char,int>(foo);

}
```

то есть хочется чтобы работало и как-то так :

```
int main() { 
    auto F1 = F1_func(foo);
}
```

Comment: ¿А зачем здесь `F1_func`? Проще было бы сразу создавать экземпляр класса.

Comment: @user7860670 а я так не умею. у меня так не получалось. не удалось с передачей в конструктор функцию.  поэтому я подсмотрел у функций bind и binder. один класс, другой функция :)

Comment: @user7860670 а с функцией у меня вышло. и я подумал, что так и надо делать и поэтому так и сделано в биндерах. но выяснилось, что функция должна принимать параметр другого типа. а разницу между этими типами я не очень понимаю

Answer (score 7, accepted):

А если так написать, вам годится?

```
template<typename arg0, typename res0>
F1<arg0, res0> F1_func( arg0(*_func)(res0)) {
    return F1<arg0, res0>(_func);
}
```

Вы же передаете указатель на функцию, а не структуру...

Comment: гениально ! а можете объяснить почему в вашем случае параметры автоматически определяются , а в моём (когда параметр функции имеет тип typename F1<arg0, res0>::func _func) - нет.

Comment: это не его случай,  а общее правило  указывать правильный тип

Comment: Потому что вы указываете не тот тип, который передаете. Фактически вы говорите своим кодом — эй, компилятор, преврати-ка эту функцию в объект F1 и передай мне ее в качестве аргумента, а я уж в функции верну копию. Кстати, в этом смысле ваша функция не имеет особого смысла: вы по сути возвращаете то, что передано в нее. Как упрощенный пример — функция для превращения `int` в `double`, которая по логике должна быть `double i2d(int i) { return double(i);}`, но у вас получается `double i2d(double d) { return double(d);}`. Т.е. преобразование выполняется не в функции, а до нее.

Comment: объясню свои мотивы: я предполагал , что вот этот тип аргумента F1<arg0, res0>::func в моей функции подсказывает, что в качестве аргумента мы хотим видеть не объект структуры , а именно тип func который там описан как typedef arg(*func)(res x);

Comment: ```struct ooo {
    typedef int myint;

};

void foo1(ooo::myint f) { return; }
int main() {
foo1(555);
}``` например  этот пример. мы указываем тип параметра ooo::myint f. разве тут будет неявное преобразование в ooo::myint f ? а не просто в int ???

Comment: по поводу "Кстати, в этом смысле ваша функция не имеет особого смысла" я эту функцию делал потому что не понимал как без неё создать объект структуры . поэтому я списал этот метод по аналогии как это реализовано например в bind, binder . Но я до сих пор не пойму почему вы утверждаете , что будет неявное преобразование при передаче в параметр указателя на функцию в объект структуры, если я там указал не объект структуры , а тайпдеф структуры ))

Comment: то есть я не очень понимаю в чем разница между типами в аргументе функции arg0(*_func)(res0) и typename F1<arg0, res0>::func .

Comment: Тогда ("*не понимал как без неё создать объект структуры*") все еще проще: все, как у вас, выбрасываем функцию вообще, и просто пишем `F1 f = foo;`. VC++ 2019 спокойно это съедает (если только силком не заставлять его соответствовать стандарту C++14).

Comment: не,  я так не хочу ) хочу как у негодяя брюсика (который эккель) а он писал свой второй том в нулевых годах, кстати в моем сырце ошибка. в определении структуры F1. псевдоним func описан с перепутанными местами аргументом и результатом.

Comment: @Harry А ваш самый первый головной ответ был в точку.

Answer (score 2):

Промежуточная функция `F1_func` не нужна, в актуальной версии С++ параметры шаблона выводятся из аргументов конструктора.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename arg0, typename res0>
struct F1
{
    typedef arg0 arg;
    typedef res0 res;
    typedef arg(*func)(res x);
    func f;
    F1(func _f) : f(_f) {}
    res0 operator()(arg0 x) { return f(x); }
};

char foo(int u) { return 's'; }

int main()
{ 
    F1 f1{foo};
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+arg0,+typename+res0%3E%0Astruct+F1%0A%7B%0A++++typedef+arg0+arg%3B%0A++++typedef+res0+res%3B%0A++++typedef+arg(*func)(res+x)%3B%0A++++func+f%3B%0A++++F1(func+_f)+:+f(_f)+%7B%7D%0A++++res0+operator()(arg0+x)+%7B+return+f(x)%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Achar+foo(int+u)+%7B+return+!%27s!%27%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B+%0A++++F1+f1%7Bfoo%7D%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142004/discussion-on-answer-by-user7860670-----).